# how to print 3 lines in 1 column?

Tags: sorting, awk, sed, paste, cut

I've a file like below.

```
ab13p29im-sss29511
0
Jan 12 22:43
ab13p29im-sss29531
0
Jan 12 22:43
ab13p29im-sss29512
0
Feb 2 16:11
ab13p29im-sss29522
0
Feb 2 16:12
ab13p29im-sss29532
0
Feb 2 16:12
ab21p30im-sss30511
0
Jan 12 22:43
ab21p30im-sss30531
0
Jan 12 22:43
ab21p30im-sss30512
0
Feb 2 16:13
ab21p30im-sss30522
3
Feb 2 16:12
```

i want to print this is below format.

```
ab13p29im-sss29511 0 Jan 12 22:43
ab21p30im-sss30522 0 Feb 2 16:12 
ab21p30im-sss30531 0 Jan 12 22:43
```

I'm using the command `paste - - - < inputfile`.But if any of the value is null, the format is all messed up like below?

```
ab13p29im-sss29511 0 Jan 12 22:43

ab21p30im-sss30522 0 ab21p30im-sss30531 

0 Jan 12 22:43  ab21p30im-sss30523.
```

Like if there's no date for any host or if any value is null, it breaks the 3,3,3 pattern.

Comment: Can you give example on what gets wrong.  Also use code tags in your post. Select text when edit and click this button `{}`

Comment: "I have a problem" "Here is some data that does not demonstrate my problem" "Help me solve my problem". Doesn't make sense when it's written like that, does it? Edit your question to show data that demonstrates the problem you want us to help you solve.

Answer (score 3):

You like some like this:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":RS' file
ab13p29im-sss29511 0 Jan 12 22:43
ab13p29im-sss29531 0 Jan 12 22:43
ab13p29im-sss29512 0 Feb 2 16:11
ab13p29im-sss29522 0 Feb 2 16:12
ab13p29im-sss29532 0 Feb 2 16:12
ab21p30im-sss30511 0 Jan 12 22:43
ab21p30im-sss30531 0 Jan 12 22:43
ab21p30im-sss30512 0 Feb 2 16:13
ab21p30im-sss30522 3 Feb 2 16:12
```

Comment: thanks but the problem here is if there's no date for a hostname all the format will be messed . like if any value among the 3 columns is null then the format goes bad.

Comment: Can you then update you post and give example on data that goes wrong.  By null do you mean that the line is missing, so it break the 3,3,3, lines pattern?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 'N;N;s/\n/ /g' YourFile
```

Load 2 lines, remove new line before printing it then cycle

you could secude by putting a pattern check to initiate the cycle like `/[a-b0-9]\{9\}-[a-b0-9]\{8\}/!d;` before first `N`

Answer (score 0):

By using `awk` command and explicit concatenation:

```
$ awk 'NR % 3 == 1 { lines=$0 ; next } { lines=lines" "$0 } NR % 3 == 0 { print lines ; lines="" }' file
ab13p29im-sss29511 0 Jan 12 22:43
ab13p29im-sss29531 0 Jan 12 22:43
ab13p29im-sss29512 0 Feb 2 16:11
ab13p29im-sss29522 0 Feb 2 16:12
ab13p29im-sss29532 0 Feb 2 16:12
ab21p30im-sss30511 0 Jan 12 22:43
ab21p30im-sss30531 0 Jan 12 22:43
ab21p30im-sss30512 0 Feb 2 16:13
ab21p30im-sss30522 3 Feb 2 16:12
```